# How to set google.com in Edge as default search (and not local version of search)?

Tags: windows-10, google-search, microsoft-edge, search-engines

I want to use google.com (global) as default search engine in Edge on Windows 10.

Once I choose www.google.com from the list of discovered search engines (settings / advanced settings / choose search engine) it instantly switches to a local version (google.pl).

How can I force Edge to use google.com as search engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your default search engine to `google.com/ncr`